# Call to a member function redirect() on string - Yii2 v2.0.36

Tags: php, yii2

When I try to redirect to url from the my controller's init() function, I get this message **Call to a member function redirect() on string**.

```
public function init()
{
    $someCondition = myBoolFunction();
    if ($someCondition) {
        return $this->redirect('my/url'));
    }

    parent::init();
}
```

Comment: You have a parse error `))`

Comment: It's a typo while writing the example, but it's not the issue in the actual code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to call `$this->redirect()` **after** `parent::init()`, since `$response` property (used by `$this->redirect()`) is [initialized there](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/2.0.39.2/framework/base/Controller.php#L109).

```php
public function init() {
    parent::init();

    $someCondition = myBoolFunction();
    if ($someCondition) {
        return $this->redirect('my/url'));
    }
}
```

But in general `init()` is not a good place to do such redirection (it probably won't even work, since `init()` shouldn't return anything, so your redirection may be ignored), you should use `beforeAction()` instead. [Here you can see how to configure response in `beforeAction()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51012072/yii2-return-response-during-beforeaction/51012348#51012348), just replace `asJson()` with your redirection:

```php
public function beforeAction() {
    parent::init();

    $someCondition = myBoolFunction();
    if ($someCondition) {
        $this->redirect('my/url'));
        return false;
    }

    return parent::beforeAction();
}
```